# tmux exits with [exited] on mac os x

Tags: macos, tmux

I just installed [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/) (a terminal multiplexer) with homebrew. When I try to run it, it always exits with `[exited]` Nothing shows up.

When I try to run `tmux list-session` I get an error:

> failed to connect to server: Connection refused

I tried running `tmux start-server`, but again nothing happens.

What can I do?

Comment: start using the -v option to increase verbosity

Comment: Check your `default-command` and `default-shell` options. If *tmux* is having trouble running your default command (or shell) it will respond like you are describing. For further investigation, you can use do something like `tmux new /bin/zsh` to explicitly start with (e.g.) `/bin/zsh` instead of relying on `default-command` or `default-shell`.

Comment: `tmux new /bin/zsh` worked for me. Thank you.

Comment: Er, my suggestion was meant as a diagnostic step, not a final workaround. There is probably something buggy about your `default-shell` or `default-command` setting.

Comment: I recently found (for the first time) that if 1) .tmux.conf exists but has syntax errors or 2) .tmux.conf is a symbolic link that links to nothing, tmux will not open. It might be good to try at first with the default configuration file so first `mv $HOME/.tmux.conf $HOME/.tmux.conf.backup` and see if tmux starts. @ChrisJohnsen is right, your solution simply means that there is a bug afoot.

Comment: I'm having this same problem. Chris, what exactly do you mean when you say there's something wrong with default-shell or default-command?  I removed my tmux.conf file altogether and I'm still getting the error.

Comment: @AdamAlbrecht: I just came across your comment (*start* your comment with `@username` to notify a user that is participating in the comment thread). If you are using the default values of `default-shell` and `default-command`, then you should check the value of your SHELL environment variable. *tmux* will attempt to start an instance of your SHELL when you do not give it a command (and `default-command` is empty, like it is by default). Maybe something (shell initialization file?) is setting your SHELL environment variable to a pathname that does not exist, is inaccessible, or not executable.

Answer (score 206, accepted):

I had this same problem. It was caused by having `set-option -g default-command "reattach-to-user-namespace -l zsh"` in my `.tmux.conf` without having [reattach-to-user-namespace](https://github.com/ChrisJohnsen/tmux-MacOSX-pasteboard/) installed.

The fix was to install "reattach-to-user-namespace" via Homebrew (`brew install reattach-to-user-namespace`)

Comment: great thx! Exactly what was missing on my system to make it work!

Comment: `+1` Thanks a ton! I had exactly the same issue. Do you know any way to set options conditionally so it won't fail on a system that doesn't have `reattach-to-user-namespace` installed?

Comment: @padde See [this solution](https://github.com/jimeh/dotfiles/commit/3470b1632fff4e97426e41a4c20fbb385688b782).

Comment: Any idea how to achieve this in Ubuntu? Tried looking for a way to download `reattach-to-user-namespace` but my efforts were futile.

Comment: @DaMainBoss `reattach-to-user-namespace` is for tmux only. If you're on ubuntu just comment out that line from your .tmux.conf file

Comment: Four years later and this saved me from tearing my hair out. Thanks!

Comment: This wasn't the answer for me, but it lead me to the solution. My default-shell and default-command were still searching for a shell I recently deleted. Changing them to a default system shell /bin/ksh resolved this for me.

Comment: Duh. Yes. And this will probably happen every time I set up a new computer. :o

Answer (score 92):

In my situation I had been fiddling with a number of dotfiles so expected things to be amiss. My fix happened to be shutting down tmux with `killall tmux`. After this I was able to spin up properly.

Comment: This worked for me, I already had reattach-to-user-namespace installed

Comment: worked for me. i did not have anything related to "reattach-to-user-namespace" in my conf

Comment: I suspect this is related to @mhansen's answer about it happening when updating tmux. I believe I updated tmux via Homebrew and then ran into this. Worked after "killall tmux". Presumably the old version of tmux still had sessions open causing this issue. For google-ability, the full error output for me was "[exited] ^[[?62;4c^[[ITERM2 3.4.4n".

Comment: I received the commend field for creating a new tmux session after upgrading python from 3.7.9 to 3.12.1. Killing tmux process fixed it.

Answer (score 8):

This happened to me just after updating tmux, while I still had an old version of tmux running.

If you've just updated tmux, quit all the running tmux sessions and it should work again.

Answer (score 7):

Do make sure that the **default-shell** option only contains the executable path and does not contain options.

In `/etc/tmux.conf` or `~/.tmux.conf`

```
set-option -g default-shell "/bin/bash"
set-option -g default-command "bash -l"
set-option -g default-path $HOME
set-option -g default-terminal "screen-256color"
```

Comment: This answer led me to the real reason, I had just uninstalled tcsh, and my default shell and default command were still set to it. Changing it to /bin/ksh, or a default installed shell of your choice, fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a script to wrap `reattach-to-user-namespace`, as outlined by [jimeh](https://github.com/jimeh/dotfiles/commit/3470b1632fff4e97426e41a4c20fbb385688b782), don't forget to make the script executable with `chmod +x ~/bin/login-shell`.